# second cycle not start in bash

Tags: bash, recursion

I need to withdraw all dir without tree. I dont know why second cycle doesn't start.

```
#!/bin/bash
recurse() {
  for i in "$1"/*;do
    echo ""
    y=$(($2 + 0))
    for j in $(seq 0 $y); do
      echo -n "|--' "
    done
    if [ -d "$i" ];then
      echo "|--$i"
      recurse "$i" "$(($y + 1))"
    elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
      echo "file: $i"
    fi
  done
}
    
recurse $1 "0"
#echo -n "|-b"
```

Comment: Btw.: when you indent your code, it becomes more readable.

Comment: Note that right now, none of your variables (`i`, `j`, etc) are local -- so inner instances of your function changing them will modify behavior of the outer instances. And you _don't_ need to quote `"0"`, but _do_ need to quote `$1` -- `0` will only ever be exactly one word, but `$1` can expand to an arbitrary number of words if it isn't quoted, depending on its contents.

Comment: Declare your variables `local`, and then use `set -x` to enable trace-level logging (those logs will be on stderr, so you can use `bash -x yourscript . 2>file.trace` to redirect them somewhere separate from your output). Reviewing that trace should help you identify the specific problem, and thus build a narrower question around it.

Comment: ...and btw, I'd also suggest avoiding `seq` -- it's a nonstandard command, and also not part of the shell itself so every copy you run takes time to start up, and there aren't any guarantees that different OS vendors' versions will work the same way. `for ((j=0; j<y; j++))` is preferable -- it's bash-only syntax, but guaranteed to be available and work the same way everywhere bash is installed. There are equivalents for non-bash shells too; see http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/counting

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what the OP means by '*second cycle doesn't start*' so fwiw ...

The OPs code does work for me but needs some work on the indentations for successive calls of the function ... either a) move the `|--` inwards for each recursion or b) extend the number of hyphens for each recursion (eg, 2nd pass would use `|----`.

Assuming the OP wishes to indent the `|--` by 3x additional spaces for each successive recursion level, one idea:

```
recurse() {
    local pfx
    pfx="   ${3}"
    [[ -z "${3}" ]] && pfx='|--'

    for i in "$1"/*;do
    #      echo ""
        if [ -d "$i" ];then
            echo "${pfx} $i"
            recurse "$i" "$((${2} + 1))" "${pfx}"
        elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
            echo "${pfx} (file) $i"
        fi
    done
}
```

**NOTE**: Thanks to Charles Duffy for nagging me on local vs global.

Test run on my system (w/ the `echo ""` commented out):

```
$ cd /
$ recurse etc 0 | head -50                                                                                     
|-- (file) etc/DIR_COLORS
|-- (file) etc/aliases
|-- etc/alternatives
   |-- (file) etc/alternatives/README
   |-- (file) etc/alternatives/mta
   |-- (file) etc/alternatives/mta-aliases-man
   |-- (file) etc/alternatives/mta-mailq
   |-- (file) etc/alternatives/mta-mailq-man
   |-- (file) etc/alternatives/mta-newaliases
   |-- (file) etc/alternatives/mta-newaliases-man
   |-- (file) etc/alternatives/mta-sendmail
   |-- (file) etc/alternatives/mta-sendmail-man
|-- (file) etc/bash.bash_logout
|-- (file) etc/bash.bashrc
|-- etc/bash_completion.d
   |-- (file) etc/bash_completion.d/gapplication
   |-- (file) etc/bash_completion.d/gdbus
   |-- (file) etc/bash_completion.d/gresource
   |-- (file) etc/bash_completion.d/gsettings
   |-- (file) etc/bash_completion.d/vim-completion
|-- etc/crypto-policies
   |-- etc/crypto-policies/back-ends
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/gnutls.config
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/krb5.config
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/libreswan.config
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/nss.config
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssl.config
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensslcnf.config
   |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/config
   |-- etc/crypto-policies/state
      |-- (file) etc/crypto-policies/state/current
|-- etc/dbus-1
   |-- etc/dbus-1/system.d
      |-- (file) etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.kde.kf5auth.conf
      |-- (file) etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.kde.kio.file.conf
|-- etc/defaults
   |-- (file) etc/defaults/Cygwin.bat
   |-- etc/defaults/etc
      |-- (file) etc/defaults/etc/DIR_COLORS
      |-- (file) etc/defaults/etc/aliases
      |-- (file) etc/defaults/etc/bash.bash_logout
      |-- (file) etc/defaults/etc/bash.bashrc
      |-- etc/defaults/etc/crypto-policies
         |-- (file) etc/defaults/etc/crypto-policies/config
      |-- (file) etc/defaults/etc/cygserver.conf
      |-- (file) etc/defaults/etc/hosts.allow
```

'course, this assumes the OP wants to print the full (relative) path on each line of output ...

Comment: I would _strongly_ suggest adding `local i pfx` to the top of your function just to make it easier to think about what variables' values are at any point in time. As it presently is, calling a new copy of `recurse` can update the values _used in the parent instance after it returns_. This means that `pfx` can be changed by the child copy of the function you start, and will _stay_ changed until it's reassigned again, even after that copy of the function has returned.

Comment: (Using `$y` as a global is probably not ideal either; do you want `$2 + 1` in that position instead?)

Comment: `local i pfx` breaks the current code of indentation; sure, could change the coding further to pass along the current pfx to the next call, then again, as coded the following is not changing the parent's version of `pfx`: `pfx=xxx ; recurse etc 0 ; echo ${pfx}` => `xxx`; the `$y + 1` was my goof due to cutting-n-pasting OPs code and missing that edit - updated, thanks

Comment: `echo ${pfx}` strips spaces due to missing quotes. Change it to `echo "$pfx"` and you'll see that indentation has been added. See that reproduced in the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/uQUFqY

Comment: BTW, part of why I frown on relying on bash's global-by-default behavior particularly when teaching recursion is that folks are presumably going to try to use what they're learning in other languages; and (thankfully) that behavior is rare -- JavaScript is the only other commonly-used language that comes to mind with the design misfeature in question. If the OP tries to use their same logic in Python or Scheme or C or... well, anything else... and has it suddenly not work, that's going to be surprising & mean they won't have learned good practices around recursion that they can use elsewhere.

Comment: `echo "${pfx}"` still prints just `xxx` in both of my `bash` environments(4.4.12 and 5.0.0);  but I do understand what you're saying ... and upon reviewing the ouput (in the answer) it's not resetting pfx at the topmost level so ... one more try to fix that and address your concerns (even though not changing pfx=xxx at the parent) ...

Comment: If the original version was not changing the value in the parent, why is the value in the stdout of  https://ideone.com/uQUFqY (running bash 5.0) indented? Or, to make it more clear, see https://ideone.com/JYktFx with separate before and after `echo`s.